# PyCuda C++ kernel "error: this declaration may not have extern "C" linkage"

Tags: cuda, pycuda

I tried using `std::tuple` in my kernel code, but received many `error: this declaration may not have extern "C" linkage` errors that pointed to `utility` and `tuple`

It complains on the include. The following repros for me.

```
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
mod = SourceModule("""#include <tuple>""")
```

Do I need to do something special in my kernel code or in my Python code to specify I want to use the C++ compiler?

Cuda version: 11.8

PyCuda version: 2022.2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I need to do something special in my kernel code or in my Python code to specify I want to use the C++ compiler?

To be clear, you are using the C++ compiler. But PyCUDA automagically wraps the code you pass into a [`SourceModule`](https://documen.tician.de/pycuda/driver.html#pycuda.compiler.SourceModule) instance in `extern “C”` unless you explicitly tell it not to:

> Unless no_extern_c is True, the given source code is wrapped in `extern “C” { … }` to prevent C++ name mangling.

The underlying reason from a C++ perspective is that templated instances of types and functions can’t resolve with C linkage, thus the error.

However, even after you fix that problem, prepared to be disappointed. CUDA supports a lot of C++ language features, but it doesn’t support the standard library and you can’t use `std::tuple` within kernel code. NVIDIA does provide their own (very limited) [reimplementation](https://nvidia.github.io/libcudacxx/standard_api.html#utility-library) of the C++ standard library, and it does have a basic tuple type. That *might* work for you.

Comment: std::tuple can be used in kernel code with `--expt-relaxed-constexpr`